# Can a function return a mapped tuple without noUncheckedIndexedAccess errors?

Tags: typescript, tuples, undefined, mapped-types

The code example below cannot compile with noUncheckedIndexedAccess. While `literalValue` is known to be a number, the `value` and `spreadValue` variables have 'undefined' in their type union.

Is there any way to annotate the squareTuple and squareSpreadTuple functions, so that passing a tuple of a specific arity will return a result which can be destructured like a literal tuple, without a spurious undefined arriving in its type union?

The Mapped type in the example code was an attempt do do this (by passing on the length attribute of the tuple to its return). It seems to have no effect.

Is there anything else which can be done to transfer the arity of the argument tuple to its returns in a way that destructuring would respect?

```
function square(num:number){
  return num*num;
}

type Mapped<NumList extends ReadonlyArray<number>> = ReadonlyArray<number> & {length:NumList["length"]}

function squareTuple<NumList extends ReadonlyArray<number>>(nums:NumList): Mapped<NumList> {
  return nums.map(square);
}

function squareSpreadTuple<NumList extends ReadonlyArray<number>>(...numList:NumList) : Mapped<NumList> {
  return squareTuple(numList)
}

const [literalValue] = [9,16,25] as const;
const [value] = squareTuple([3,4,5] as const) ;
const [spreadValue] = squareSpreadTuple(3,4,5) ;

console.log(`Sum of values is: ${literalValue + value + spreadValue }`)
```

The example code (with the visible compile errors) is at [this playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=19&pc=72#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAZwI4gIYCcCmAKMEAWwC5CiAjHLASgG8AoRRXKELJcgKnIG4GAvgwZQAngAcciALIZxkgCYAeAHLEAMjGRREOAB5QcYBckQAlHBgUIANqICCWLBlFLyVLAD5PiALznLazA7R2dXd2ofADJEOhsjAHMoAAsSNSJNbQBtACJ4sCTknIBdIQZQSFgEFHRsHAAVEHF41Q0tHX1DY1MLK1sHJxc3Yg9vAmJkNLbtGhIZOUVWjPafRmZWdk4JgDoiOTw0TFwafjKK6HgkQ7qAZXFcK0bmnCXMjoMjEwC%204IGw4cokU8eG2oPIbymyxmiDmsnkOGU6TeqyYLBwbA4NSODSa8XGUKgNEEwggCG0iCyNhghmcNgAahgbCAcMU-BSAJwAGgAjAA2TkAJgArKyMKZSWBtPwJeSsgA3RnM1n%20a64J54rIAZk5ABZOSLEGLEDLCYhpWSdFlkPdAgymSy2aqcHcHgp1fhtXqhTQzSSyXB4tsbHAEngAAY3YiIODARAK%202mLRzAAkcWp1EZduZiAA1HHFVI89bXVmpAIwzQgA)

***UPDATE***

I managed to get the red lines to go using the code at [this playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAZwI4gIYCcCmAKMEAWwC5CiAjHLASgG8AoRRXKELJcgKnIG4GAvgwZQAngAcciAEo4MAEwQAbUQBUQ4pTgA8qgHyIAvDLmKwK7QG0AdLdWWAug738REqQFkM4yfO0AZGGQoRBwADygcMHlkEwVlNQ0tbQwwUT0DY0ZmSwBJaPDEGCQAaxxROGBEQOCHEmqgqDyCsId%20AUQAMkQ6LTAAcygAC3qapoByPsGh8YchBlBIWAQUdGwcdU0dADliMdCIqJi4sxVN5PIqLAyCYmQSXaIxmnqvHxw-R7GDbJYcNg4iHIyGsRG8eDQmFwNEQGFi4BKYDgAHckHDEG9fNovo0XIJhItoPAkJD1gBlcS4BTnHZ7RoHSLRWKyeLmRJbbSXag3WzWchjB504Iw17eLE44I-Jh-AEkta4Gm3J6NGHozEfbFCqB6fEMCAIYJArVGRCWADMABoACwWgCsDlhsX1YGC-GdhtJuH2xksAE4LQBGABsFoATPbHYh3VA3QaQpYlDBIlgMEoAGqpkA4B3GfmNWMu%20MAN0z2ZNno2SXweeFiALhssyEppgzSizOdWUJwFKp8kVlpttphrndcC01iUcH6eAABmTiIhKogS22cLEgvUACS9JPUVOtrOIADUy9Lx5QzYUB6kAhnNCAA). This is by no means elegant for something that's a built-in type where I would expect this to be inferred. Probably there is a better way.

***UPDATE 2***

If I extend support only to the spread case, then the more minimal approach at [this playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAZwI4gIYCcCmAKMEAWwC5CiAjHLASgG8AoRRXKELJcgKnIG4GAvgwZQAngAcciALIZxkgCYAeADIxkURDgAeUHGAXJEAbQB05jGFHGAujYB8iALyJGzYwEkDOxDCQBrHFE4YEQ1DRsSMPUoT29tG34BRAAyVwAbfQBzKAALKPDYgHJMsBzcopshBlBIWAQUdGwcABUQcUylADliQq1dfUMTc1NyKixbBwJiZBIeokKaKNl5HGV5wsc3Fhw2DkRyZFMiOTw0TFwaRAwjcH8wOAB3JBuZOUVu3pj7JOFa6HgSHOzQAyuJcBgFG0OjhPgsYv09AYjGZzGNqJN7HgRuRCnMvhorst3ms4ZtXEwdnsgU1cNDMtN4YTrkYVh8Nt9BMIIAgNCZ0jA9FgMOkAGoikA4GzOEwAZgANAAWeUAVmlrx5YA0-E1fOMDywJzFEqlMuBdPaDOMCuVapoDF1mmMyHBOEh4vSkulLnNODBEKhlvwNtVV34Dt5cEypnScCyeAABiDiIgQogAG4mozqKIAEjoAqFIo9ksQAGoDnBDcWTeWUK73bWBAmaEA) works. I find it hard to explain why the non-spread case won't compile using this simpler approach, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My inclination would be to write `Mapped` like this:

```
type Mapped<L extends readonly number[]> = { readonly [K in keyof L]: number }
```

This is using TypeScript's support for [using mapped types to turn arrays/tuples into arrays/tuples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays).  Such mappings already preserve the `length` property without you having to do anything in particular.  Presumably all you're trying to do with `Mapped` is to undo any [numeric literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) inference and widen back to `number`.  That's what the above `Mapped` does.  Let's test it out:

```
type Test = Mapped<[1, 2, 3]>;
// type Test = readonly [number, number, number]
```

Looks good.

---

As you noticed, the compiler will not be able to verify that the implementation of `squareTuple()` will satisfy the call signature's return type.  The [TS standard library's typings for `Array.prototype.map()`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/322c70fd8259b2beef001e1a346fc75ab070dbea/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1361) specify that it returns an array, not a tuple. Some [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) are in order, such as:

```
function squareTuple<NumList extends ReadonlyArray<number>>(nums: NumList): Mapped<NumList> {
  return nums.map(square) as readonly number[] as Mapped<NumList>;
}
```

After this everything should work:

```
const [literalValue] = [9, 16, 25] as const;
const [value] = squareTuple([3, 4, 5] as const);
const [spreadValue] = squareSpreadTuple(3, 4, 5);
console.log(`Sum of values is: ${literalValue + value + spreadValue}`); // okay
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAZwI4gIYCcCmAKMEAWwC5FCiAjHLASkQG8AoRRXKELJCxAKnOIBuJgF8mTKAE8ADjkQBZDNNkATADwAZRDgAeUHGBXI2ODCoQAbSQKo0A2gF0AfIgC8jE2cvW7AaUQwSADWOJJwwIgaDmQU1FiIIsISMnIAKjjIUG4KSqpqdgCMADSIAEwlAMzOwgD0NYhSsojpmdm4XmBWiHaxNCW9WP3EcQ7ioJCwCCjo2DipINIWOGoAcsQaMK26+obGAEqm5p2SAIJYWBiSagNOTgTEyGRrRBuZtGSKyjjqz69QLsxWOxONwHgA6IhKPBoTC4egYYztI5dAaORAInJfH7rTb-YRiJjjaDwJAw2YAZWkSPmi2Wv1x2j0BiMiAOHSsZwuVxudzBfIofyeOLeH1y31Wwv+jBYJg4XGmsLmCyW9xeuNoonEEAQrTsFhg+guFgAahgLCAcA5snYAJwlAoANhKpQArFaMdqwJlhJ7dQA3M0Wq3uMm4GkquwVEoAFhKbvRxl9UFoPp1WTsyCph1N5st2VDOEp1OV+CjiFjiBdKaYvrgSzBFjgAHM8AADcnERDhRAB3PGTZkAAkDH1hrNOYtiAA1D3A3IZ5mkROcCJWynEHUu0FLkA)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to map the tuple type. Casting to NumList is necessary though, Array.map() can return an empty array, but we know that it is not empty.

```ts
function squareTuple<NumList extends readonly [...number[]]>(nums:NumList): NumList {
  return nums.map(square) as unknown as NumList;
}

const [constValue] = squareTuple([3,4,5] as const); 
// const normalValue: 3, doesn't matter
const [normalValue] = squareTuple([3,4,5]); 
// const normalValue: number

const [emptyConstValue] = squareTuple([] as const); 
// const emptyConstValue: undefined 
// error: Tuple type 'readonly []' of length '0' has no element at index '0'
const [emptyValue] = squareTuple([]); 
// const emptyValue: undefined
// error: Tuple type 'readonly []' of length '0' has no element at index '0'

const [literalValue] = [3,4,5];
console.log(`Sum of values is: ${literalValue + normalValue }`)
// "Sum of values is: 12"
console.log(`Sum of values is: ${literalValue + emptyValue}`)
// error: Object is possibly 'undefined'.(2532)
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAZwI4gIYCcCmAKMEAWwC5CiAjHLASgG8AoRRXKELJcgKnIG4GAvgwahIsBCnTYcAFRAAHADY4APADliAGRjIoiHAA8oOMABNkLHBlMJFAT0QBtAHSvyVLI4C6XgHwFiZBINIm1dGhJEELC9RmZWdk5A5yIMeTw0TFwaRAwLcABrMDgAdyQ8qK0dKH4hBggEXScGsF0ANQxFEBwvRABeSSzZBWU8RwBmABoAFkmAVl6KlvDeRHrGvUdirFTFDq6e-sHpOSV8CZn5rxp+Zc2cInkoOwBhDf3u3oHMk5HzxYsdxuazuTgeTzsH0O3ykuFOo28wOEoMcihgxiwnShXycU1mC1ujTgymcijgAHM8AADADKxEQcGAiAAbp1uhYdJEACR0NEYrFsnCIADUiG2uyhiAEVJoDCAA)